# unfinished installation of pgadmin4 keeps blocking other installations

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, pgadmin

I have been trying to install pgAdmin4 but I get this error below, I tried to resolve the error and I couldn't, so I decided to go on with my installations, then I tried Mongodb, it also can't install

```
 sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.4.2 mongodb-org-server=4.4.2 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.2   mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.2 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: mongodb-org-database-tools-extra but it is not going to be installed
 pgadmin4 : Depends: pgadmin4-web but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

but still no positive yields as the error persists

How can I fully remove pgAdmin, I mean anything related to postgres, so that I re install a new fresh bundle.

Comment: First pgAdmin != Postgres. pgAdmin is just a GUI client. So have you tried `sudo apt remove pgAdmin4`?

Comment: Yeah, I ran this but  I think the problem is that I have two unfinished installations of different versions of postgresql that are blocking each other from finishing the installation, so how do I solve that? My quest would have been removing everything related to postgresql but I can't also

Comment: Unless you installed Postgres using the EDB installer `pgAdmin4` has not relation to Postgres. So how did you install Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my `dpkg` config. but this helped me out

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed/